# Jquery onclick show li, hide ALL syblings li and children element

Tags: jquery, html-lists, hide, show

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    ul ul
    {
        display: none;
    }
    ul li
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul li').addClass('reveal');
        $('.reveal').live('click', function (event) {
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
            $(this).siblings('li').children().slideUp();

        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<ul>
    <li>a
        <ul>
            <li>inner1
                <ul>
                    <li>bonner1
                        <ul>
                            <li>donner1<ul>
                                <li>konner1</li>
                                <li>konner2</li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>donner2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>bonner2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>inner2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>b
        <ul>
            <li>inner3</li>
            <li>inner4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to close all sybling inner elements on li click event. This code works, but not in a desired way.It close sybling element but not and child elements inside of sybling element. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is:

```
$(this).siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
```

That will slideup all `<ul />` elements nested within the sibling `<li />`s.

Is that what you want?

Comment: @Inrbob, Yes :). I've tried with     $(this).siblings('li').children().find('ul').slideUp(); Now I have learned that find() function search for all descendant elements. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How to add this function to my code :`enter code here`

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/te366hu2/2/